# Configuring Grails/Sonar in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, grails, sonarqube

We have SonarQube 6.4 and Groovy plugin installed. With a Maven project, the report will be sent to SonarQube by using sonar:sonar as Maven goal.

In a Grails project, sonar-project.properites has been created in root folder as:

```
sonar.projectKey=com.example.fw
sonar.projectName=My Project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.sources=src/groovy,grails-app/jobs
sonar.language=grvy
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Which grails command should be used to generate report in SonarQube? Where to set the URL/token for SonarQube server?

I'm using Eclipse 3.6 with GGTS for Grails/Groovy project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just use the sonar scanner tool, a command line client, that works fine.